# Why was this custom flag declined

Tags: discussion, off-topic-questions, flagging, closing

Recently I asked [this](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/47740/how-is-the-urdu-word-%D8%A7%D9%8E%D9%88%D8%B1-written-in-hindi-%E0%A4%94%E0%A4%B0-or-%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0) question and it was closed(as per the moderators/community etc) because [it](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/47740/how-is-the-urdu-word-%D8%A7%D9%8E%D9%88%D8%B1-written-in-hindi-%E0%A4%94%E0%A4%B0-or-%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0) isn't suitable/meant for this linguistics site. And I can see that linguistics site isn't the best place for my posted question.

But when flagged a [similar question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38764/is-there-any-word-in-other-languages-that-begins-with-the-urdu-alphabet-%e1%b9%9b%c4%93-%da%91) as [that question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38764/is-there-any-word-in-other-languages-that-begins-with-the-urdu-alphabet-%e1%b9%9b%c4%93-%da%91) also doesn't seem to be suitable for this linguistics site and so that should also be closed, the custom flag was declined without giving any good reason. The reason they said they declined was

> Declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see

---

So I think that since the same rules apply to all the questions/post, either the [linked question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38764/is-there-any-word-in-other-languages-that-begins-with-the-urdu-alphabet-%e1%b9%9b%c4%93-%da%91) should also be closed as it also isn't suitable/meant(imo) for the linguistics site or [my question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/47740/how-is-the-urdu-word-%d8%a7%d9%8e%d9%88%d8%b1-written-in-hindi-%e0%a4%94%e0%a4%b0-or-%e0%a4%85%e0%a4%b5%e0%a4%b0) should be reopened.

I may be wrong in thinking that the [linked question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38764/is-there-any-word-in-other-languages-that-begins-with-the-urdu-alphabet-%e1%b9%9b%c4%93-%da%91) isn't suitable for linguistics site just like my question, so I want to confirm if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, please use standard flags for flagging a question as off-topic.

Also, each question is considered on its own merits. There are lots of old questions that probably should be closed but fell through the cracks. Just because one question wasn't noticed years ago doesn't mean a new question shouldn't be closed now when we do notice it. And if those old off-topic questions come to our notice later on, then we can and do close them.

Comment: My point is that when I flagged that question for the moderators, I clearly wrote that it does not belong to the linguistics site and so even though the flag was declined(as a more suitable flag exists), the question should at least be closed. Also, at that time I was not aware that there was another flag option called "off topic" so I flagged it for moderators. Now I've flagged it again as "off-topic". I am not demanding to reopen my question, but to close the one I flagged. Also, even though the question is asked some years ago, it must still adhere to the site rules without bypassing them.

Comment: No one gets to *demand* a question be closed. When I saw your flag, I did consider whether the question should be closed. I thought it was borderline, but not enough for an immediate mod-only closure. By using the correct flag the rest of the community can weigh in on whether the question meets the site standards or not. Custom flags should only be used for situations with no appropriate standard flag which require immediate mod attention rather than being something others in the community can also solve.

Comment: *"No one gets to demand a question be closed."* Why not? If something is wrong, as a user I can demand for the right action to be taken. You should not discriminate on the basis of the age of the question. In your previuos comment, you said that *"not enough for an immediate mod-only closure"* so why did you close my question which also should not require mod-only closure? It(my question) should also be closed by the community(i assume by three votes like on SO).

Comment: I see only two votes on my closed question, one by the community member and the 2nd one by the moderator.

Comment: @user12002570 Because I judged that your question was not borderline and warranted immediate closure. Moderators can immediately close questions without needing to wait for five close votes, so the mods try to avoid closing borderline and disputable questions. As an experienced Stack Exchange network user these should not be foreign concepts to you.